# Zip'ануть картинки налету из стрима, не сохраняя файл на диск

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Задача поставлена так:
Нужно извлечь все картинки из html-страницы и сжать их Zip'ом не сохраняя при этом на диск.
Реализовать на C#.

Собственно картинки я скачиваю и даже на лету сжимаю зипом не скидывая их на диск пода проблема в том что из например 3 картинок всегда остается последняя третья.
Будто они затираются каждый раз.
А мне нужно чтобы все 3 были в архиве.

Вот пример кода  который с набросал.

```
        public byte[] GetImage(String urlTo)
        {
            MemoryStream compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            String source = client.DownloadString(urlTo);
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(source);

            foreach (var link in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"]))
            {
                String ext = Path.GetExtension(link.Value);
                if (ext == ".jpeg")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(link.Value);
                    byte[] data = client.DownloadData(link.Value);
                    using (compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
                        {
                            string name = link.Value.Split('/').Last();
                            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(name);
                            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(data))
                            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                            {
                                originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return compressedFileStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: `foreach` перенести внутрь юзинга `zipArchive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На каждой итерации цикла `foreach` вы пересоздаёте `zipArchive`. Поэтому нужно перенести цикл внутрь.

К тому же я бы посоветовал отказаться от устаревшего класса `WebClient` и применить `HttpClient`. При этом лучше использовать асинхронные методы.

В итоге код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetImageAsync(string urlTo)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string source = await client.GetStringAsync(urlTo);
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(source);

        using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
            {
                foreach (var link in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                    .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"]))
                {
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(link.Value);
                    if (ext == ".jpeg")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(link.Value);

                        string name = link.Value.Split('/').Last();
                        var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(name);

                        using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(link.Value))
                        using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        {
                            await stream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return compressedFileStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Ещё лучше иметь всего один экземпляр `HttpClient` на приложение. Поэтому следует вынести его из метода и сделать, например, статическим полем.

Comment: `using (var client = new HttpClient())` - пересоздавать клиент на каждый запрос - так себе практика (могут сокеты истощиться, то есть закончиться), лучше вынести в `private static readonly client = new HttpClient()`. Его в таком случае задиспозит GC финализатором при выходе из приложения. Я думаю, есть смысл поправить сниппет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!
Все работает!